# aws iot publish failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, esp32

I'm trying to connect to AWS-IoT using my own MQTT-client (because of learning and more control for later tasks). I can connect and also get a connack-message, but when i try to publish, the connection closes.

I already enabled CloudWatch and get the following events:

```
{
"timestamp": "2019-03-03 11:41:26.629",
"logLevel": "INFO",
...
"status": "Success",
"eventType": "Connect",
"protocol": "MQTT",
"clientId": "ESP32_e839169e",
...
}

{
"timestamp": "2019-03-03 11:41:57.065",
"logLevel": "ERROR",
...
"status": "Failure",
"eventType": "Publish-In",
"protocol": "MQTT",
"topicName": "a/b",
"clientId": "ESP32_e839169e",
...
}

{
"timestamp": "2019-03-03 11:41:57.073",
"logLevel": "INFO",
...
"status": "Success",
"eventType": "Disconnect",
"protocol": "MQTT",
"clientId": "ESP32_e839169e",
...
}
```

(I did not send the disconnect, it came from aws)

My policy document should not be the problem, because I got the basicPubSub-Example with the same certificate-files to work. Here is my policy document:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "iot:Publish",
        "iot:Subscribe",
        "iot:Connect",
        "iot:Receive"
        ],
    "Resource": [
        "*"
        ]
    },
    {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": [
        "greengrass:*"
        ],
    "Resource": [
        "*"
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Because I'm using my own MQTT-Client, i cannot fully guarantee, that my message is completly correct.

Here is my message:

```
Byte -  Hex - Char - Meaning

   0 - 0x30 - 0    - message type, flags -> Publish, dub = false, qos = QOS0, retain = false
   1 - 0x13 -      - message length      -> 19 Bytes
   2 - 0x00 -      - topic length        ->  3 Bytes
   3 - 0x03 - ╚
   4 - 0x61 - a    - topic               -> a/b
   5 - 0x2f - /
   6 - 0x62 - b
   7 - 0x00 -      - packed identifier   -> 0
   8 - 0x00 -  
   9 - 0x74 - t    - payload             -> test_payload
  10 - 0x65 - e
  11 - 0x73 - s
  12 - 0x74 - t
  13 - 0x5f - _
  14 - 0x70 - p
  15 - 0x61 - a
  16 - 0x79 - y
  17 - 0x6c - l
  18 - 0x6f - o
  19 - 0x61 - a
  20 - 0x64 - d
```

What am I doing wrong? And is there a way to get more information from aws, what the problem is?

Comment: AWS can be pretty opaque - if you're not getting useful details from its logs can you try against a local server that you can control? Mosquito is lightweight and easy to install; there's a small chance its logs might give you more details. Or if your client works correctly with Mosquitto that'll point towards an AWS policy problem.

Comment: yes, I thought about this too - but it's a lot of work for me. But I think this is the only way for me at the moment...

Comment: I have a similar issue using MQTTnet v 3.0.2 where it connects successfully (I can see it in the AWS logs) but the Publish-In event fails. The payload is a simple string. I have checked my AWS IAM roles etc to ensure it's nothing on the Policy side; I did this my using the MQTTfx utility that uses the same Certificate files and profiles....and the Connect+Publish-In function perfectly, these can be seen in the logs. My MQTTnet client connects but fails to Publish triggering a TimeOut error on the client side. I may decide to use a different C# library.....